# Specific date format conversion problems in R

Tags: r, date

Basically I want to know why `as.Date(200322,format="%Y%W")` gives me `NA`. While we are at it, I would appreciate any advice on a data structure for repeated cross-section (aka pseudo-panel) in R.
I did get `aggregate()` to (sort of) work, but it is not flexible enough - it misses data on columns when I omit the missed values, for example.
Specifically, I have a survey that is repeated weekly for a couple of years with a bunch of similar questions answers to which I would like to combine, average, condition and plot in both dimensions. Getting the date conversion right should presumably help me towards my goal with zoo package or something similar.

Any input is appreciated.

Update: thanks for string suggestion, but as you can see in your own example, `%W` part doesn't work - it only identifies the year while setting the current day while I need to set a specific week (and leave the day blank).

Comment: Hi Alex,
Can you clarify what you are trying to do here.  What time are you trying to represent?  If you want to put 2/2/2003, you might want to try something like:
  as.Date("20030202",format="%Y%m%d")
Also, be sure to put your date as a string, otherwise it will want to interpret the date as the number of seconds from some origin.

Comment: The second part of your question should probably be split out into a new question and give much more detail.  What does your data look like?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a string as first argument in `as.Date()` and select a specific weekday (format `%w`, value 0-6). There are seven possible dates in each week, therefore `strptime` needs more information to select a unique date. Otherwise the current day and month are returned.

```
> as.Date(paste("200947", "0", sep="-"), format="%Y%W-%w")
[1] "2009-11-22"
```

Comment: But why `format(as.Date("2003-06-02"),"%Y-%W")` gives `"2003-22"`, and `as.Date("2003-22","%Y-%W")` gives `"2003-11-23"` (month and day is from current date)

Comment: You have to specify the number of a weekday (`as.Date("2003-22-1","%Y-%W-%w")`), otherwise there is no unique result and the current day and month are returned.